# Matplotlib plot without linear ordered

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to draw matplotlib chart without using a pandas plot to draw a chart without linear ordering the values on the left?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'x':[3,0,5],
'y':[10,4,20]
})
```

Chart made with the help of DataFrame:

```
plt.barh(df['x'],df['y'])
```

Without dataframe:

```
x = [3,0,5]
y= [10,4,20]
plt.barh(x,y)
```

it gives me the same result

Matplotlib chart
Output chart:
[image]

```
df.plot.barh('x','y')
```

Pandas output chart:
[image]

I would like to get such an output only with normal numbers and not numbers as the type of str

```
plt.barh(['3','0','5'],[10,4,20])
```

[image]
Is it possible? How could i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of the dataframe as `y` parameter and use the `x` values of the dataframe as `tick_label`:

```python
plt.barh(df.index, width=df['y'], tick_label=df['x'])
```

[image]